# APScheduler Set misfire_grace_time globally

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am trying to apply `misfire_grace_time` globally for all of my jobs. According to the [Doc Page](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html#missed-job-executions-and-coalescing) it says:

> The scheduler will then check each missed execution time against the job’s `misfire_grace_time` option (which can be set on per-job basis or globally in the scheduler) to see if the execution should still be triggered.

but how do I set it globally?

I tried:

```
sched = BackgroundScheduler(misfire_grace_time=30)
# a few sched.add_job()
for job in sched.get_jobs():
    print(job.misfire_grace_time) # Throws exception
```

but doing `sched.add_job(...., misfire_grace_time=30)` or `job.misfire_grace_time = 30` in the for loop works.

What is the correct way of setting `misfire_grace_time` globally without adding it to each individual job?

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: @AlexGrönholm it just says job.misfire_grace_time not exist

Comment: Please edit the post to include the entire traceback.